# How do I adjust for covariates using Kruskal Wallis in SPSS?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, spss, kruskal-wallis-test, predictor, adjustment

Do i need to do another test after KW to account for covariates or is there a way to account for covariates when doing the initial KW test in SPSS?

Comment: To summarize the answer to the question that I marked as a duplicate: use ordinal regression, not Kruskal-Wallis.